# TypeScript - Error: Debug Failure. False expression:

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou tentando criar uma definição de módulo Node.js. Tenho o arquivo `poolredis.ts`, mas quando eu adiciono a linha:

```
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';
```

O compilador TypeScript me dá o erro:

> Error: Debug Failure. False expression:

Como posso corrigi-lo?

Comment: Traduzi a sua pergunta, pois este é o StackOverflow em português. Caso tenha algum erro ou você queira adicionar mais informações é só você editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer importação de 3 maneria sendo 1 delas dessa forma, caso de erros
tente procrurar os **types** que nesse caso tem então faça a instalação deles com o seguinte comando

```
npm i @types/redis --save
```

caso continue o erro você pode fazer a importação de outro jeito sendo de 2 formas diferentes, sendo elas a seguinte:

```
const redisClient = require('redis');
```

**OU**

```
import * as RedisClient from 'redis';
```

caso persista o erro precisar ver a documentação da biblioteca.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -s @types/redis
```

Acho que é só isto.